# Загрузка файлов на сервер в приложении Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Вопрос в заголовке, собственно. Как реализовать загрузку файлов (изображений) на сервер в приложении Meteor ? Деплой планируется на digital ocean.

В сети много разрозненной информации, но какого-то решения я не нашел.

В английском SO советуют использовать amazon s3. Поэтому вторая часть вопроса насколько это оправданно, если функционировать сайт будет на территории России (преимущественно Москва), деплой планируется на digital ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Для загрузки фотографий локально я использовал вот такой [плагин](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) пример использования есть, а на счет загрузки на s3 я не реализовывал но рассматривал возможность с использованием плагина [Amazon S3 Uploader](https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Можно узнать, почему предпочли загрузку на сервер, а не использование s3? Насколько я понял, в запущенном рабочем состоянии у проекта от этого одни плюсы.

Comment: после рассмотрения вариантов руководство предпочло локальное хранение

Comment: Я имел в виду, что вы наверняка знаете плюсы и минусы локального хранения vs использования сервиса наподобие s3, руководству же должен был кто-то донести информацию. поэтому я прошу поделиться этой информацией, потому что для меня сейчас выбор совсем не очевиден, из-за нехватки опыта по существу. заранее спасибо.

Comment: в s3 самые главные плюсы я думаю как всегда что не нужно иметь инфраструктуру для хранения информации  у себя и нести издержки по ее обслуживанию, доступность всегда и везде где есть интернет, а наш выбор локального хранения это всего лишь ретроградное мышление.

Answer (score 0):

Привет!
Для загрузки рекомендую использовать вот этот пакет: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

Он хорош. Отличная альтернатива не поддерживаемому ныне CFS.
Опять же автор осуществляет оперативную поддержку пользователей.

По поводу  s3 скажу - для личных проектов их рассматривать не стоит. Все же это хранилище может влететь в копеечку.